# How to detect the middle other element which is not the first and last in protrcator

Tags: javascript, css, protractor, gulp-protractor

In Protractor, Say I have 5 elements with the same class/model/binding/repeater tags.

For example:-

```
Guest 1 - $2345
Guest 2 - $2345
Guest 3 - $2345
Guest 4 - $2345
Guest 5 - $2345
```

So, to inspect the first and last element we will write code something like this:

```
element.all(by.css('')).first();
element.all(by.css('')).last();
```

Now, how to detect the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element using the same css tag?

I was thinking of taking the for loop.. but not able to proceed.

Comment: Try using `element.all(by.css('').get(2)` for 2nd element and so on

Comment: @KishanPatel You should add this as answer. Though 2 as index will get the 3rd element, as index starts at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .get() , index starting from 0

```
let second = $$('LOCATOR').get(1)
let third = $$('LOCATOR').get(2)
let forth = $$('LOCATOR').get(3)
expect(second.getText()).toEqual('Guest 2 - $2345')
```

Also you can look on this lib - 
https://github.com/Marketionist/protractor-numerator

Answer (score -1):

Following code will fulfill your requirement:

```
 element.all(by.css('locator')).each(function(ele,index){
    return ele.getText().then(function(eleText){
         if(eleText=expectedEleText){
          return ele;
         }
    });
 }).then(function(reqElement){
  //perform required operations on 
 });
```

Comment: The question is not to search based on text but position of the element. Even so you are better off using filter method and your if condition needs the equality operator '==' or '===' instead of '='